# Scanner only reads file name and nothing else

Tags: java, parsing, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to implement a rudimentary lexer. I'm stuck on the file parsing at the moment.

```
public ArrayList<Token> ParseFile () {

    int lineIndex = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(this.fileName);

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

        lineIndex++;
        String line = scanner.nextLine();

        if (line.equals(""))
        continue;

        String[] split = line.split("\\s"); 
        for (String s : split) {
        if (s.equals("") || s.equals("\\s*") || s.equals("\t"))
        continue;
        Token token = new Token(s, lineIndex);
        parsedFile.add(token);

        }
    }
    scanner.close();
    return this.parsedFile;
}
```

This is my fille called "p++.ppp"

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std ;

int a ;
int b ;

int main ( ) {

    cin >> a ;
    cin >> b ;

    while ( a != b ) {
        if ( a > b )
            a = a - b ;
        if ( b > a )
            b = b - a ;
    }

    cout << b ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

When I parse the file, I get: `Error, token: p++.ppp on line: 1 is not valid` but p++.ppp is the file name!

Also when I debug, it reads the file name and then at `scanner.hasNextLine()` it just exits. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've misunderstood the API for `Scanner`. From the docs for the [`Scanner(String)` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.String%29):

> Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified string.
>
> Parameters:
>   **source** - A string to scan

It's not a filename - it's just a string.

You should use the `Scanner(File)` constructor instead - or better yet, the `Scanner(File, String)` constructor to specify the encoding as well. For example:

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(this.fileName), "UTF_8")) {
    ...
}
```

(Note the use of a try-with-resources statement so the scanner gets closed automatically.)

Comment: Yes, I admit only glancing over the scanner api. I don't think I even looked over the constructor. Thank you. I do however get `The constructor Scanner(File, Charset) is undefined`

Comment: @Kalec: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: 1.7.0_13 runtime environment build b20

Comment: @Kalec: You're right - there's no `Charset` overload, weirdly enough. Not sure why I thought there was. Editing...